# Share SSH Public Key?

Tags: database, windows, ssh, server, key

I would like to ask if it is dangerous to pass on an SSH public key {name}.pub file to others, or if this only applies to the private file. (2nd question) Is the SSH key reset when I reset Windows?
The file was for a friend so that he can log me on to a server. I don't really have any security concerns, I'm just a bit paranoid.

*Thanks for reading :D*

Comment: The public key can safely be shared with others. That's why it's named **public** key.

Comment: But with the public key, no one can access my computer, right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question seems to *"Need more focus"*, please consider the guidelines [*"Why are some questions closed??"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

First of all public key is meant to be public (i.e) You can share it without fear (this doesn't mean it should be public).

Assuming that you use ssh for login remote server. The public key is the place for the server and the private key lives in the client machine.

**How public key authentication works?** 
To keep things simple, You probably generate an RSA(a cryptographic algorithm) public and private key pair, then you place the public key in a remote server and keep the private key within your client machine. When you log in with ssh, the server sends a challenge (some data encrypted with the public key). This challenge can only be decrypted with the private key in your machine. Your machine will decrypt and re-encrypt the challenge with your private key (again this can only be decrypted with the public key in the server). If the process goes correct, then the server knows that you have the right private key and it allows you access(here no secrets are shared).

You can't generate a private key with the public key, so there is no issue if the public key is leaked.

To answer your second question:
The private key is stored in your local machine, if you reset your OS, probably the key will be lost and you cant access the server. You can copy the private key safely somewhere before resetting OS and paste the key after the new OS installation (not recommended, do with caution). Or you can create a new RSA key pair and add the public key to the server(recommended).

Note: As you mentioned in the question **The file was for a friend so that he can log me on to a server**. Your friend cannot actually log in with a public key. The private key is required at the client-side.