# How to securely distribute PGP public keys?

Tags: code-signing, gnupg

GPG signing is a bit different compared to signtool on Windows and codesign on Mac, as PGP certificates are self-signed and there is no chain of trust. So, say someone develops an application on Linux and signs the RPM installer using rpmsign (which uses gpg as the underlying signing tool), they would have to distribute their public key to the customers. How can this be achieved in a secure manner? I don't think the developer wants to bundle their public key in the release package, as that can be easily faked. What do commercial product teams on Linux usually do to distribute their public keys?

[UPDATE] I looked into "Web of trust". I think I need to make sure my question is clearly understood. Take some Linux desktop application for example. If I am developing a commercial product on the Linux platform, I want to sign my application installer (an RPM file) so that my customers have confidence on the installer that they get. On Windows and Mac, this can be achieved by signing the installer (.exe or .pkg) and then the customer can verify its signature on their side. They can trust the public key because signing on these platforms is done with an X.509 certificate which is issued by a publically trusted CA (e.g. DigiCert), and there is a chain of trust - The customer trusts DigiCert, and DigiCert trusts my company, so the customer trusts my product.

With GPG signing, as the certificate is self-signed, that chain of trust is missing. I will need to somehow distribute my public key to the customer, so that the customer can use it to verify the signature in my installer. If I package the public key and the installer in a ZIP archive, the customer would have little trust in the content in this archive because everything inside can be faked by some threat actor in the middle. My question is around how I can securely distribute my public key to the customer, so that they trust that the key is not compromised. I am not sure how "Web of trust" could help. The software publisher will need to get the public keys from their customers? I don't think that is realistic for the software publisher. What is the common approach for commercial product developers to follow on Linux?

Comment: A public key is supposed to be shared publicly. That's the reason for that name. Are you sure about your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449890/share-ssh-public-key

Comment: Yes. absolutely. The point is the public key can be easily faked. A threat actor can easily intercept the whole package and fake everything inside (the public key, the RPM installer, etc.). My question is how do commercial products usually do on Linux when it comes to distributing their public keys.

Comment: @fhcat Check for "Web of trust", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust

Comment: I updated the question with my detailed comment.

Comment: You have to share the public key via a trusted channel (or through an untrusted channel, but having it verified by a CA). See e.g. https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rpm-gpg-verify-packages , wherein GPG keys are described as being downloaded by yum/dnf from known links (the user is also prompted to verify their correctness).  The critical section of the package is recalculated after download and compared to the decrypted, signed values.  Because the package contents themselves are not encrypted, it is usually possible for the user to install the package without successful signature verification.

Comment: You may publish fingerprint of your PGP key on your main website. If customers know who you are, they can find you in the internet (the official website, social network account, etc.). If customers don't know who are you (you are just an unknown reputation-less developer for them), your signature means nothing.